# How does one solve $\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta \geq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I need this in order to solve:

> How does one solve $$\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta  \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Are you trying to identify the values of $\theta$ for which is is true? Or are you trying to show that this holds for every $\theta$? In any case, do you only know trigonometry, or do you know anything about calculus?

Comment: yes i'm trying to indentify the values of \theta .. i dindn't know very much

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left(\sin^ 2 x + \cos^2 x\right)^2 = \sin^4 x + 2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x +\cos^4 x
$$
so we have
$$
1 = \sin^4 x + 2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x +\cos^4 x\implies \sin^4 x +\cos^4 x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x\cos^2 x 
$$
$$
2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 (2x)
$$
can you finish this off
$$
\sin^4 x +\cos^4 x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}\sin^2 (2x)
$$

Comment: omg that's all ? ..tks so much

Comment: No worries - If it is any consolation I have answered a similar question to this on this site.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

$sin^4 + cos^4 = (sin^2)^2 + (1 - sin^2)^2$

so if $z = sin^2$

$z^2 + 1 - 2z + z^2 = \frac{1}{2}$

then $z = \frac{1}{2}$

so it is an equality where $sin^2\theta = 0.5$

so you will then have plus and minus values for $\sin \theta$ and you have to figure out how the inequality lies

Comment: Actually, you can rewrite this inequality as $2(z-1/2)^2\geq 0$, which means...

Comment: yes I should have realised that, instead of fiddling around proving it was >=1/2 at all different places

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A,$

$$(2\sin^2y)^2+(2\cos^2y)^2=(1-\cos2y)^2+(1+\cos2y)^2=2(1+\cos^22y)=2+1+\cos4y$$

Now, $-1\le\cos4y\le1$

Alternatively, $2(a^2+b^2)-(a+b)^2=(a-b)^2\ge0$